# Strange DNS or IP hosting related issue

Tags: php, dns, hosting

I have just opened a hosted web site on a hosting company, but the main page doesn't render properly.
When I load it through the IP, it works great.
When I load it through the domain name, the style is messed up.

Domain example : http://newluckybags.com/index.php?categoryID=1

IP example : http://109.199.126.180/~newlucky/index.php?categoryID=1

It seems like a sever issue from the hosting service, but still I feel I should research it and get other experts' opinions on it :)

To see the problem, use the domain and wait for the load to complete.
Then scroll up and down and wait for a while.

Comment: I see the opposite problem. The styling seems incomplete on the IP version, where I notice a bunch of 404 errors.

Comment: Removed bloat, removed redundancies, improved grammar and phrasing, fixed spelling.

Comment: also while i access the website through IP there are there are lots of js and css getting 404 means path is wrong there. if file already there on the path then did you check the files permisssion?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the two pages don't have the same css files.

[image: Photo of files]

You can check these files in your navigator. In addition the files downloaded in the page without domain delay the page charge most of 50 seconds that I know because I must closed the page

Answer (score 0):

Use Absolute Path for js, css and images.

i.e

Relative Path:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/staticContent/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
```

Absolute Path:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://newluckybags.com/staticContent/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://109.199.126.180/~newlucky/staticContent/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
```

Your domain website and IP website running on differant URL. so it's not loading js, css and images with same relative path.

http://newluckybags.com/

http://109.199.126.180/~newlucky/